# PHP EOF shows only one result from loop

Tags: php, loops, eof

I am using in my PHP EOF.

The problem is that it does display only one item coming from a mySQL loop.

It shows only the last result.

Is this necessary in EOF? or can I avoid this issue?

Thanks

```
function getYiBAdminBanner() {
global $site;
global $dir;
$queryYiBmenu = "SELECT * FROM `(YiB)_cPanel_Menu` WHERE Type = 'top'";
$resultYiBmenu=mysql_query($queryYiBmenu) or die("Errore select menu: ".mysql_error());
$countYiBmenu = mysql_num_rows($resultYiBmenu); 
while($rowYiBmenu = mysql_fetch_array($resultYiBmenu)) {
$menu = "<div id=\"menu\" style=\"display:none;\"><li><a href=\"".$site['url'].$rowYiBmenu['linkHref']."\" onMouseOut=\"javascript: $('#menu').hide('9000');\"><img class=\"imgmenu\" src=\"".$site['url'].$rowYiBmenu['linkIcon']."\">".$rowYiBmenu['linkTitle']."</a></li></div>";
}
if($countYiBmenu <= 0){
$menu = "No Modules Installed";
}
$bannerCode .= <<<EOF
<div style="width:520px; background-color: #EEE; height:30px;">
{$menu}
</div>
EOF;
return $bannerCode;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: Are you looping through a mySQL result or a file?

Comment: I am looping through a mySQL result. There is no code to show. The question is simple. Should I post two pages of code? @Felix Kling I do not think you need such a thing.

Comment: If you are looping through `mysql` results you should not be using any "`EOF`" as far as i know (this is for file handles). You should be using `mysql_query -> mysql_fetch_assoc or mysql_fetch_array -> while loop`. See my example.

Comment: *There is no code to show* and *Should I post two pages of code* contradict each other. Anyway, your question is not clear to me, you are talking about "EOF" (whatever that is) and MySQL results and I cannot see a connection between those.  I was just trying to help, good luck solving the problem!

Comment: Just added the code. I hope it helps

Comment: FYI, that thing you call "EOF" is actually called a heredoc and you can use another identifier besides `EOF` to make it work: http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-heredoc-syntax.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: based on your code sample: try `$menu .= <your result>` or `$menu = $menu . <your result>` rather than `$menu = <your result>`. But its unclear if you are expecting multiple results or not

If you are looping through the results of a mySQL query you should be doing something like this:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT firstname, lastname, address, age FROM friends WHERE firstname='%s' AND lastname='%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($firstname),
    mysql_real_escape_string($lastname));

// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['firstname'];
    echo $row['lastname'];
    echo $row['address'];
    echo $row['age'];
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

If you are looping through the contents of a file you should be doing something like this:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("welcome.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
//Output a line of the file until the end is reached
while(!feof($file))
  {
  echo fgets($file). "<br />";
  }
fclose($file);
?>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file.asp

[php manual fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

I hope that helps but your question isn't very clear on how/where your using EOF.

Comment: I am looping in the very same way you are doing on the first solution. I have only one row to show. So I then assign that variable to the EOF in this way {variable} . It is showing only one result, the last one. It is not showing all the results given by the mySQL loop

Comment: 'I have only one row to show' - do you mean 'I have only one COLUMN to show' ? and of that you have many ROWs you are looping through but only the last ROW is being displayed? You really need to post just the code relating to the loop. It is basically impossible to "debug" your problem without seeing your code because you speak of "EOF" but i don't know what that is. I think possibly you are reassigning the variable over itself every time you loop. You need possibly to be storing the variable as an array something like this: `$myVariable[] = $row["YOURCOLUMNAME"];`

Comment: ... if you have something like this within your loop: `$myVariable = $row["YOURCOLUMNNAME"];` then of course each time you loop through the rows of your results the variable will be overwritten with the latest row until you reach the end and it is set to the last result. Thus you might need `$myVariable[] = $row["YOURCOLUMNAME"];` to set to an array.

Comment: you are using `$menu = <results>` if you have multiple results in the query result you should be using `$menu .=` But i'm confused in your first comment you say 'i have only ONE ROW in the results' but then you say 'is only showing one result' so i don't know if you expect multiple results and you have a typo or not. But make sure to but `.=` to concatenate if you expect multiple results

Comment: Now it is showing only the first result instead the last. But anyway it is not showing all the results..I do not really know where the problem is..

Comment: you need to do debug printing inside that function. Try putting `print $menu; exit;` after the loop (before `$bannerCode .= <<<EOF...`) The `$menu` var should be setting correctly now. Hopefully you can see where its going wrong by excluding the $bannercode, EOF etc Good luck!